# trying to prevent event from firing from a jquery function on site

Tags: jquery

I am in need to override a function or prevent an event called from firing.
Unfortunately I cannot do a code deployment and thus cannot change the core code.

Here is the method that is executing nail the tail end of the HTML page.

```
module.exports = function () {
    var $pdpMain = $('#pdpMain:not([class*="gift-card"])');

       $pdpMain.on('mouseenter', '.swatches.size', function () {
            $('.bx-creative').show();
        }).on('mouseleave', '.swatches.size', function () {
            $('.bx-creative').hide();
        });
};
```

I have access to the CMS area which is right above this function:

I just need to remove the .mouseleave event so that when I mouse over the .swatch.size area, it wont hide the content that has a class of bx-creative.

I have tried:

```
module.exports = function () {
$(".swatch.size").mouseleave(function (e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   return;
});
};
```

But that is not correctly working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the top code, you have `.swatches.size`, but `.swatch.size` in your code. Should this be `.swatches.size` too?

Comment: thank you typo. corrected, but the .mouseleave is still firing and cause .bx-creative to hide

Comment: so stupid I am... i just did the inverse... since there is a event handler to hide on mouseleave. I just created another event on mouseenter everywhere else. FIXED.